# Resharper stop newline before return

Tags: c#, return, resharper, newline

in C#, whenever I type a single line statement that includes `return`, formatting with ReSharper causes it to place the `return` indented on a new line.

I get this:

```
if(x == 0)
    return;
```

But I want this

```
if(x == 0) return;
```

I can find no option for changing the setting and it's driving me nuts.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

In Resharper options, under Code Editing -> C# -> Formatting Style -> Line Breaks and Wrapping, set `Break line in single embedded statement` to either `Do not change`, or, `Force put on single line`.

[image]

Comment: Tried BOTH.  Neither is working.  Soon as I format the document, BAM, my return statements move down to the next line.  I sure hope I'm not forced to reset everything.

Comment: Have you made sure you've saved the Resharper settings? Maybe try clearing the Resharper cache and restart Visual Studio.

Comment: Yeah , they're saved. I'll try clearing the cache. Bummer.  Naturally, it works fine when I wrap the return in a block: `{ return x; }`, so I might consider doing that as well, as the braces help the return to stand out. Thanks for the assist.

Comment: That pesky cache.

Comment: scratch that, it's back AGAIN, after working for a week.  And this time, no amount of adjustment, including clearing cache and resetting back to factory everything has any impact.  So frustrating!

Answer (score 2):

Found another possible solution to this insidious problem:

`Options > Text Editor > C# > Formatting > Wrapping`

Check `Leave statements and member declarations on the same line`.  This is, of course, misleading and inaccurate, as in my example, there is no member declaration, but it's worth a try if anyone else gets caught.